# Create custom thumbnail size on existing posts

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm applying a new theme to my site, and the theme has a custom thumbnail size.  I realize that `add_image_size()` does the work of creating the custom thumb whenever a new post is created.

This in my theme's **functions.php**:

```
add_image_size('ttrust_threeColumn', 280, 170, true);
```

However, I have a bunch of old posts I need to create this thumbnail size for.  These old posts have a filename stored in a custom "Thumbnail" field, e.g.:

```
/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/this-is-my-post-thumb.jpg
```

I can grab that file path with this:

```
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Thumbnail')
```

Now if I loop through all the old posts, how can I create the custom **ttrust_threeColumn** thumbnail size for each post?

I appreciate the help!  I've tried a bunch of different functions and methods, but I can't seem to get a grasp on thumbnail creation for existing posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Banjer,

Afaik add_image_size works for new IMAGES, and not for new posts, but regardless of this I think all you need to do is regenerate your thumbnails with the must-have "regenerate thumbnails" plugin.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: That worked, thanks.  I found Ajax Thumbnail Rebuild to be a little more user friendly and better performance-wise:  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/